# query() of generator `max_length` being succeeded

Tags: python-3.x, huggingface-transformers

Goal: set `min_length` and `max_length` in Hugging Face Transformers generator query.

I've passed `50, 200` as these parameters. Yet, the length of my outputs are much higher...

There's no runtime failure.

```py
from transformers import pipeline, set_seed
generator = pipeline('text-generation', model='gpt2')
set_seed(42)

def query(payload, multiple, min_char_len, max_char_len):
    print(min_char_len, max_char_len)
    list_dict = generator(payload, min_length=min_char_len, max_length=max_char_len, num_return_sequences=multiple)
    test = [d['generated_text'].split(payload)[1].strip() for d in list_dict]
    for t in test: print(len(t))
    return test

query('example', 1, 50, 200)
```

Output:

```
50 200
Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:50256 for open-end generation.
1015
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Explanation:

As explained by Narsil on Hugging Face  Transformers [Git Issue response](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/15914#issuecomment-1058112592)

> Models, don't ingest the text one character at a time, but one token
> at a time. There are different algorithms to achieve this but
> basically "My name is Nicolas" gets transformers into ["my", " name",
> " is", " nic", "olas"] for instance, and each of those tokens have a
> number.
>
> So when you are generating tokens, they can contain themselves 1 or
> more characters (usually several and almost any common word for
> instance). That's why you are seeing 1015 instead of your expected 200
> (the tokens here have an average of 5 chars)

##### Solution:

As I resolved...

> Rename `min_char_len, max_char_len` to `min_tokens, max_tokens` and
> simply reduce their values by a ~1/4 or 1/5.